When precisely does APP_INITIALIZER run?
I have a name of the environment embedded into the app component like:
<app-component env="dev" />

I need to get some configuration from the backend based on this attribute on the app-component.
This config has to be in place before any other call to the backend happens (since they all use this config).
What/when is the best way to handle it?
Is APP_INITIALIZER a proper way to do it? Or does APP_INITIALIZER happen even before I can access app-component attribute?
The other option I can consider is just a global js/ts variable within index.html.
The third option is a resolver/guard on / route.

Using JS function getElementsByTagName you should be able to get the element and obtain its attribute value. After that, you can start executing desired BE calls.
export function appInit(/*params*/): () => any {
  const appComponent = document.getElementsByTagName('app-component').item(0);
  const env = appComponent?.getAttribute('env');
  console.log('Env:', env);
  return () => { /* do stuff */  };
}

But I would recommend using environment variable, which can be set for various environments, replaced by build script and easily accessible. Just import it where needed. You can then use it either in APP_INITIALIZER, or anywhere else in the code, see.

How would I ensure appInit resolves and gets values before any other call in the app? Does APP_INITIALIZER guarantee that?

APP_INITIALIZER is designed in this way. When the init function returns Promise or Observable, the application waits for its execution and only then proceeds with bootstrapping the app. If there's some code in app-component (or any other entry point), it won't execute before initializer is done.

ahow is APP_INIZIALIZER related to components onInit? the reason asking is: i need to read that env attribute on main component before running APP_INITIALIZER.

If by main component you mean anything else than app entry point (usually app-component) than you won't be able access it in APP_INITIALIZER, since the application itself hasn't bootstrapped yet. And it's not related to onInit it happens way before any onInit call is made.

yes, sorry, I meant app-component. now when I think about it, this would not work with SSR. Seems like its better to go with global variable defined in index.html and read that in APP_INITIALIZER. Would you agree?

Definitely, we do it this way too. Even in micro frontend architecture, we can check if the standalone app is public and we either instantiate MSAL or not. And this comes from environment variables.

how did you fit in local development into that? what do you use locally to replace anchor text in main.ts? I would like to avoid ejecting and custom webpack/vite setups. any ideas there?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
